# Omnisharp vim with neocomplete not working

Tags: c#, vim, neocomplete, omnisharp

I installed Omnisharp and I am able to get autocompletion with < Ctrl+X > + < Ctrl+O >, but this is obviously not ideal as you have to keep hitting this weird combination of keys. I have also installed neocomplete bundle to try and get autocompletion while I type but I am not getting the same autocompletions that come with Omnisharp.

I tried to used these neocomplete settings supplied from the Omnisharp github page in my vimrc, which gives me an error when used on its own:
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim/wiki/Example-NeoComplete-Settings

And paired with the example settings on the main page here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim

Seems to run without errors, but again is not giving me the autocompletions that are consistent with what I get from hitting < Ctrl+X > + < Ctrl+O >

This is what my .vimrc currently looks like:

```
execute pathogen#infect()

" OmniSharp won't work without this setting
filetype plugin on

"This is the default value, setting it isn't actually necessary
let g:OmniSharp_host = "http://localhost:2000"

"Set the type lookup function to use the preview window instead of the status line
"let g:OmniSharp_typeLookupInPreview = 1

"Timeout in seconds to wait for a response from the server
let g:OmniSharp_timeout = 1

"Showmatch significantly slows down omnicomplete
"when the first match contains parentheses.
set noshowmatch

"Super tab settings - uncomment the next 4 lines
"let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = 'context'
"let g:SuperTabContextDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-o>"
"let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionTypeDiscovery = ["&omnifunc:<c-x><c-o>","&completefunc:<c-x><c-n>"]
"let g:SuperTabClosePreviewOnPopupClose = 1

"don't autoselect first item in omnicomplete, show if only one item (for preview)
"remove preview if you don't want to see any documentation whatsoever.
set completeopt=longest,menuone,preview
" Fetch full documentation during omnicomplete requests. 
" There is a performance penalty with this (especially on Mono)
" By default, only Type/Method signatures are fetched. Full documentation can still be fetched when
" you need it with the :OmniSharpDocumentation command.
" let g:omnicomplete_fetch_documentation=1

"Move the preview window (code documentation) to the bottom of the screen, so it doesn't move the code!
"You might also want to look at the echodoc plugin
set splitbelow

" Get Code Issues and syntax errors
let g:syntastic_cs_checkers = ['syntax', 'semantic', 'issues']

augroup omnisharp_commands
    autocmd!

    "Set autocomplete function to OmniSharp (if not using YouCompleteMe completion plugin)
    autocmd FileType cs setlocal omnifunc=OmniSharp#Complete

    " Synchronous build (blocks Vim)
    "autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <F5> :wa!<cr>:OmniSharpBuild<cr>
    " Builds can also run asynchronously with vim-dispatch installed
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>b :wa!<cr>:OmniSharpBuildAsync<cr>
    " automatic syntax check on events (TextChanged requires Vim 7.4)
    autocmd BufEnter,TextChanged,InsertLeave *.cs SyntasticCheck

    " Automatically add new cs files to the nearest project on save
    autocmd BufWritePost *.cs call OmniSharp#AddToProject()

    "show type information automatically when the cursor stops moving
    autocmd CursorHold *.cs call OmniSharp#TypeLookupWithoutDocumentation()

    "The following commands are contextual, based on the current cursor position.

    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap gd :OmniSharpGotoDefinition<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>fi :OmniSharpFindImplementations<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>ft :OmniSharpFindType<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>fs :OmniSharpFindSymbol<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>fu :OmniSharpFindUsages<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>fm :OmniSharpFindMembers<cr> "finds members in the current buffer
    " cursor can be anywhere on the line containing an issue 
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>x  :OmniSharpFixIssue<cr>  
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>fx :OmniSharpFixUsings<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>tt :OmniSharpTypeLookup<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>dc :OmniSharpDocumentation<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <C-K> :OmniSharpNavigateUp<cr> "navigate up by method/property/field
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <C-J> :OmniSharpNavigateDown<cr> "navigate down by method/property/field

augroup END


" this setting controls how long to wait (in ms) before fetching type / symbol information.
set updatetime=500
" Remove 'Press Enter to continue' message when type information is longer than one line.
set cmdheight=2

" Contextual code actions (requires CtrlP)
nnoremap <leader><space> :OmniSharpGetCodeActions<cr>
" Run code actions with text selected in visual mode to extract method
vnoremap <leader><space> :call OmniSharp#GetCodeActions('visual')<cr>

" rename with dialog
nnoremap <leader>nm :OmniSharpRename<cr>
nnoremap <F2> :OmniSharpRename<cr>      
" rename without dialog - with cursor on the symbol to rename... ':Rename newname'
command! -nargs=1 Rename :call OmniSharp#RenameTo("<args>")

" Force OmniSharp to reload the solution. Useful when switching branches etc.
nnoremap <leader>rl :OmniSharpReloadSolution<cr>
nnoremap <leader>cf :OmniSharpCodeFormat<cr>
" Load the current .cs file to the nearest project
nnoremap <leader>tp :OmniSharpAddToProject<cr>

" (Experimental - uses vim-dispatch or vimproc plugin) - Start the omnisharp server for the current solution
nnoremap <leader>ss :OmniSharpStartServer<cr>
nnoremap <leader>sp :OmniSharpStopServer<cr>

" Add syntax highlighting for types and interfaces
nnoremap <leader>th :OmniSharpHighlightTypes<cr>
"Don't ask to save when changing buffers (i.e. when jumping to a type definition)
set hidden

autocmd FileType cs setlocal omnifunc=OmniSharp#Complete
"Note: This option must set it in .vimrc(_vimrc).  NOT IN .gvimrc(_gvimrc)!
" Disable AutoComplPop.
let g:acp_enableAtStartup = 0
" Use neocomplete.
let g:neocomplete#enable_at_startup = 1
" Don't Use smartcase.
let g:neocomplete#enable_smart_case = 0
let g:neocomplete#enable_auto_close_preview = 0
" Define dictionary.
let g:neocomplete#sources#dictionary#dictionaries = {
    \ 'default' : '',
    \ 'vimshell' : $HOME.'/.vimshell_hist'
        \ }

" Plugin key-mappings.
inoremap <expr><C-g>     neocomplete#undo_completion()
inoremap <expr><C-l>     neocomplete#complete_common_string()

" Recommended key-mappings.
" <CR>: close popup and save indent.
inoremap <silent> <CR> <C-r>=<SID>my_cr_function()<CR>
function! s:my_cr_function()
  "return neocomplete#close_popup() . "\<CR>"
  " For no inserting <CR> key.
  return pumvisible() ? neocomplete#close_popup() : "\<CR>"
endfunction
" <TAB>: completion.
inoremap <expr><TAB>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"
inoremap <expr><S-TAB>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<TAB>"
" <C-h>, <BS>: close popup and delete backword char.
inoremap <expr><C-h> neocomplete#smart_close_popup()."\<C-h>"
inoremap <expr><BS> neocomplete#smart_close_popup()."\<C-h>"
inoremap <expr><C-y>  neocomplete#close_popup()
inoremap <expr><C-e>  neocomplete#cancel_popup()

let g:neocomplete#enable_auto_select = 0
let g:neocomplete#disable_auto_complete = 0

" Enable heavy omni completion.

call neocomplete#custom#source('_', 'sorters', [])

if !exists('g:neocomplete#sources')
        let g:neocomplete#sources = {}
endif

if !exists('g:neocomplete#sources#omni#input_patterns')
  let g:neocomplete#sources#omni#input_patterns = {}
endif

let g:neocomplete#sources#omni#input_patterns.cs = '.*[^=\);]'
let g:neocomplete#sources.cs = ['omni']
let g:neocomplete#enable_refresh_always = 0
let g:echodoc_enable_at_startup = 1
let g:neocomplete#enable_insert_char_pre = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the last line `let g:neocomplete#enable_insert_char_pre = 1` caused the error and commenting it out allowed the autocomplete to work as expected.